# efm32 - efm32gg380f1024 - rtc features

Tags: microcontroller, silicon, energysmart

I'm working with the `efm32gg380f1024` on a project.
I currently use the **BURTC** timer (ULFRC clock) as tick source and I would like to use the normal **RTC** timer(LFRC clock) as well.
Do they exclude each other or can I use both the same time?

I was wondering if someone has already experience with the GG-series of silicon labs and give me some hints?

also what I'm wondering, I do have both **LFXO** and **HFXO** on my board currently not used. when I initialize the external clock setup, can I disable the interal rcos since they are not used (??) and just need energy.
the target is battery powered and each uWs counts..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of questions here.

Yes you can use the LETIMER (which is what I think you mean when you say LERTC) peripheral independently of the RTC. They are separate peripherals, but note that the LETIMER is clocked from the same clock as the RTC.

As for using the external crystal oscillators, you need only enable the clocking sources that you actually use. However, clocking sources and entry/exit of the various low power energy modes interact. It can be rather tricky and complex. I suggest you use emlib to control these peripherals and in particular to enter and exit lower power energy modes.

If power consumption is important to you, note that high frequency clocking of the processor core consumes lots of power. Of course this must be traded off with how long you remain awake before going back to a lower power mode and with any real time requirements you might have for processing. Pushing off work to peripherals and using DMA to perform data movement is generally a win. Expect to do a good bit of tuning and you will need ways to accurately measure the power consumption. Using internal RC oscillators for clocking may be sufficient and a lower power approach. The low frequency external crystals tend to be 32 KHz clock crystals and don't consume that much power. They are a good alternative to the internal RC oscillators if you need better frequency stability.

Comment: Additionally: yes the device is always going to sleep as soon as all threads no longer need action. What i just dont know is if i use the external rc circuit with cristals if i am allowed to turn off the internal ones or if they are still used for some things? I did try to use dma with the emlib but since the emlib makes use directly of the dma with usb cdc, i can no longer use it for other purposes.. thanks for the tipps. Very welcome!

Comment: Clocks are only used if you have enabled them as a clock source in the CMU. Also, the DMA has 12 channels. There are functions in the EMDRV library to allocate channels and use the DMA. I would suspect that the USB uses that and you should be able to allocate a DMA channel for you own uses.